# combine 2 php sql query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi can someone help me put these two code together.

I'm brand new at PHP and it took me 4 hours just to get the one code to work, but now I need to combine the same two codes just with a call for another table. But no matter what I do it won't make the output it will only output the first one. The second code the error I get is:

> "ERROR: Could not able to execute SELECT * FROM treasure."

I thought it was because I close the connection in the first code so I tried removing the close but that didn't help

here is my code:

```
<?php
if($instance=="1")
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM treasure";
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql))
    {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                echo "<table id='Cheader'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Day</th>";
                echo "<th>Green Fee</th>";
                echo "<th>Cart</th>";
                echo "<th>Caddy</th>";
                echo "<th>Visitor Green Fee</th>";
                echo "<th>Note</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['day'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['cf'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['cart'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['caddy'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['viscf'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['note'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                } else
                    {
                        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
                    }
                } else
                    {
                        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . 
                        mysqli_error($link);
                    }
                    mysqli_close($link);

                 }
if($instance=="2")
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hill";
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql))
    {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                echo "<table id='Cheader'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Day</th>";
                echo "<th>Green Fee</th>";
                echo "<th>Cart</th>";
                echo "<th>Caddy</th>";
                echo "<th>Visitor Green Fee</th>";
                echo "<th>Note</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['day'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['cf'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['cart'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['caddy'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['viscf'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['note'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                } else
                    {
                        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
                    }
                } else
                    {
                        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . 
                        mysqli_error($link);
                    }
                    mysqli_close($link);

                 }

?>
```

Comment: The indentation in your code is *very* difficult to follow.  But one thing is clear... The database is telling you that there's an error but you are ignoring that error.  You need to actually *output* the result of `mysqli_error($link)` so you can *see it*.

Comment: it's because of the instance==1 it is used to load the code in to php everwhere in wp but I will try to take of the error so that I can see what it gives me

Comment: It's also not really clear how you're checking for error conditions in the first place.  Which `if` results in the `else` which outputs your error?  If it's `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` then clearly there are simply zero results from the query.  That's not a MySQL error, that's just the logic of your code.  It's up to you how to respond to that.